# Alterar script para mostrar vídeo em Html5

Tags: javascript, html5, script

Como faço para fazer esse script mostra um vídeo em HTML5 ao invés de em Flash Player? Meu script está assim:

Nesse script ele injeta o link do vídeo no flash player, eu gostaria de substituir isso  por um HTML5 do tipo `<video class="" width="100%"  controls preload="auto" autoplay poster="" src=" "></video>`

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Which flash versions are needed for given format
    var FLASH_VERSIONS = {
        '7/0/0': [5],
        '9/0/115': [18, 22, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 59, 78, 82, 83, 84, 85, 120, 121],
    }

    var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Recomendo utilizar o [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Procure por tutoriais que ensinem a execução de vídeos no HTML 5.

```
<video controls>
  <source src="foo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="foo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Seu navegador não suporta o elemento <code>video</code>.
</video>
```

Exemplo clicando em um botão para reproduzir um vídeo:

```
$('#playMovie1').click(function(){
    $('#movie1')[0].play();
});
```

Não passei como criar com JavaScript um player de vídeo, mas qualquer coisa de um `append` de um elemento do tipo `video` e manipule o mesmo com JavaScript.

Referências (espero que estes links lhe sejam úteis):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

**EDIT**

```
function addSourceToVideo(element, src, type) {
    var source = document.createElement('source');

    source.src = src;
    source.type = type;

    element.appendChild(source);
}

var video = document.createElement('video');

document.body.appendChild(video);

addSourceToVideo(video, 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv', 'video/ogg');

video.play();
```

Comment: Mas como adiona o append nesse script?

Comment: Eu queria substituir o codigo que chama o flash para um que chame o html5

Comment: Editei a resposta conforme o que você pediu, espero que ajude.

Comment: Use essa api: http://www.videojs.com/. Lembre-se de converter seus vídeos para o formato indicado, senão não vai rolar.

Comment: documentação: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/index.md

Comment: Desculpe o script que eu postei ficou faltando uma parte que busca o source do video no final do codigo, poderia olhar novamente?